# How to restrict external access to Google App Engine and only allow Apigee Edge?

Tags: api, google-app-engine, ssl, apigee

I am fairly new to GCP and Apigee both. I currently have a Node.js application on App Engine that has one simple GET endpoint.

For my use case I want people to access the endpoint through an Apigee Edge proxy and make the App Engine endpoint not accessible to anybody else.

I’ve read that one-way or two-way SSL might be the solution, but I’m fairly new to this and was wondering if you you could provide me with some directions. Thank you greatly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching about it, it seems that using mTLS is the best option for you to secure your App Engine with Apigee - as per the [Apigee Community](https://community.apigee.com/questions/53316/what-is-the-best-way-to-secure-the-connection-betw.html) on this post.

I would recommend you to take a look at the [mTLS documentation](https://developers.cloudflare.com/access/service-auth/mtls/) and you can check the documentation [API Management Platform](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/api-management/) for more information about Apigee as well.

Let me know if the information helped you!